# sendfile() blocking at linux-2.6.20-1.21

Tags: linux, block, sendfile

I use `sendfile(socket_fd, file_fd, &offset, left_size)` at **linux-2.6.20-1.21** to send a symbol link file by non-block socket. The `sendfile()` is blocking when the file size is too large(100K+).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: do you check the error code? Is it success or something like `EAGAIN`?

Comment: The `sendfile()` is blocking and not return!

Comment: ah, sorry, the error codes after the socket setup, I mean